# Continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: calculus, continuity

The question says:

Let $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\text{sin}^2(x-y)}{|x|+|y|} & \text{if $|x|+|y|>0$} \\ 0 & \text{if $|x|+|y|=0$} \end{cases}$$

Is $f$ continuous on $\mathbb R^2$?

I just can't get how to prove continuity.can anyone just give a hint for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left|\frac{\sin(x-y)}{|x|+|y|}\right|\le\frac{|x-y|}{|x|+|y|}\le1$$

so that

$$\left|\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{|x|+|y|}\right|\le|\sin(x-y)|\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}0$$

and the function's indeed continous at the origin

Comment: I just wanted to ask this doubt that we showed continuity for $(0,0)$,but what about continuity at any other point $(x,y)$.... also how is $|x-y|\leq |x|+|y|$...

Comment: @spectraa, that's the triangle inequality: $$|x\pm y|\le |x|+|y|$$ , and as for continuity in points other than the origin, the function there is the quotient of two continuous functions and the denominator doesn't vanish.

Comment: I just knew  triangle inequality to be $|x + y|\le |x|+|y|$

Comment: Well, you can prove it works just fine as written and then you learned a new thing . :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** You only have to show $f(x,y)\rightarrow 0$ if $(x,y)\rightarrow 0$. Use $|\sin(x)|\le |x|$ and the triangle inequality.